# What is the best practice to manage maven projects dependency in SVN tags?

Tags: maven, svn, tags

Suppose we have the following maven projects

```
../root/CommonCore/trunk
../root/FirsProjectCore/trunk
../root/SecondProjectCore/trunk
../root/FirstProjectSite/trunk
../root/SecondProjectSite/trunk
```

What is the best way to tag the code in SVN ?

Comment: Are those projects common, firstProjectCore, SecondProjectCore releated by a multimodule build or are they unrelated?

Comment: They are unrelated. dependency on parent is only referenced in children pom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the svn folders tags/trunk/branches for each of those projects

for CommonCore:

```
URL/commonCore/trunk
URL/commonCore/tags
URL/commonCore/branches
```

The same for the others:

```
URL/firstProject/trunk
URL/firstProject/tags
URL/firstProject/branches
```

etc. Apart from that you should never handle dependencies within SVN in no way. You have the pom files which describe those dependencies.

Tagging should be done via maven-release-plugin which will handle the above scenario automatically.